# UIButton inside UIScrollView, inside UIScrollview

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uibutton, uiscrollviewdelegate

Controller A's view contains a UIScrollview which contains a UIButton. The content scrolls vertically and the button works fine.

Controller B's view contains a UIScrollview for paging left and right.

When I place my Controller A view inside the scroll view of Controller B's the UIButton stops working.

I can't 'de-nest' the scrollviews because they are managed by independent controllers - and paging is only required under certain circumstances.

Why does Controller B stop the button from working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the UIViewController docs:

> Note: You should not use view
>   controllers to manage views that fill
>   only a part of their window—that is,
>   only part of the area defined by the
>   application content rectangle. If you
>   want to have an interface composed of
>   several smaller views, embed them all
>   in a single root view and manage that
>   view with your view controller.

The OS only bothers to send events to a single UIViewController, whichever one it thinks is active and filling the window. Only that one view controller is sure to get events including rotation method calls and memory warnings.