# UIButton doesn't interact in UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uibutton

I have a windowed (e.g. not a full-screen) `UIScrollView` (inside a `UIView`) which scrolls through groups of `UIImageViews` with `UIButtons` on them (the idea being you click the button to do something with the displayed image). The `UIButton` does take any touch events - how can I fix it?

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3132147/uibutton-inside-uiscrollview-doesnt-fire-on-tap), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167305/uibutton-inside-uiscrollview-inside-uiscrollview), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3210649/custom-uibutton-cant-interact-with-linked-uiimageview), [this](http://beerpla.net/2008/03/12/best-programming-comic-ever-code-quality-in-wtfsminute/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3544195/problem-when-using-uiimageviews-or-uibuttons-inside-a-uiscrollview) - but I either don't understand the answer or its implications, or it's not really relevant.

```
NSUInteger i;
for (i = 1; i <= kNumImages; i++)
{
    Sentence *testSentence = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] objectAtIndex:i];
    //NSLog(@"testSentence: %@", testSentence);

    //NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%d.jpg", i];
    //Your going to need to optimise this by creating another thumbnail image to use here.

    NSArray *paths       = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
    NSString *imageName = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[testSentence image]];
    //NSLog(@"imageName: %@", imageName);

    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:imageName];
    //NSLog(@"image: %@", image);

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    //NSLog(@"imageView: %@", imageView);

    [imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
    [imageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

    // setup each frame to a default height and width, it will be properly placed when we call "updateScrollList"
    CGRect rect = imageView.frame;
    rect.size.height = kScrollObjHeight;
    rect.size.width = kScrollObjWidth;
    imageView.frame = rect;
    imageView.tag = i;  // tag our images for later use when we place them in serial fashion

    imageView.frame = rect;

    UIButton *aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

    [aButton setTitle:@"Play" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    aButton.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 70, 70);
    [aButton setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [aButton setEnabled:YES];
    [aButton setAlpha:1];

    UIView *buttonWrapperUIView = [[UIView alloc] init];

    [aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(clickPlay:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [imageView addSubview:aButton];
    [imageView bringSubviewToFront:aButton];

    [scrollView1 addSubview:imageView];

    NSLog(@"aButton %@", aButton);

    [image release];
    [imageView release];
}

[self layoutScrollImages];  // now place the photos in serial layout within the scrollview
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
[imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES]
```